# scrapy parent-child (one to many)

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a spider which retrieves data from parent page (collection) then opens a link and parsed data from collection item. In scrapy.Item I expect to receive data both from parent and child pages (collection title will be repeated for each collection item).

```
class MarSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'mar'
    allowed_domains = 
    start_urls = 


    def parse(self, response):

        COLLECTION_LIST = 'div.wr_collection_list'
        collections = response.css(COLLECTION_LIST)


        for collection in collections:
            loader = ItemLoader(item=FulItem(), selector=collection)
            item = loader.load_item()
            items_url = collection.css('a ::attr(href)').get() 

            if items_url:  #

                yield response.follow(items_url, callback=self.parse_items,
                                      meta={'item': item})

    def parse_items(self, response):
        ul = response.css('ul.row')
        for li in ul.css('li'):
            if li.css('span.codice ::text'):
                item = response.meta['item']
                loader = ItemLoader(item=item, selector=li)
                loader.add_xpath('desc_text', './/div/div/text()')
                yield loader.load_item()
```

in this case after each iteration child item is appended:

> item1 collection1 desc_text_1
>
> item2 collection1 "desc_text_1, desc_text_2"
>
> item3 collection1 "desc_text_1, desc_text_2, desc_text_3"

what is the problem here. Could you show a working example?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: easiest fix is to use `loader = ItemLoader(item=FulItem(), selector=collection)` in `parse_item` instead of the one you are currently using

Comment: FullItem is already used: item = response.meta['item']. As some data is filled from parent page (in the parse function) - Full item is passed to parse_items via metadata

Answer (score 0):

```
loader.add_xpath('desc_text', './/div/div/text()')
```

this line should be replaced by:

```
loader.replace_xpath('desc_text', './/div/div/text()')
```

in this case after each loop it starts from empty instead of adding new value to array